# SVN revision number of latest change for a folder containing externals

Tags: svn

For a script I need to get the revision number of the latest change in a versioned folder (not the whole repo) to decide if the current revision has been tested already. I use:

```
svn info | grep "Last Changed Rev"
```

which returns something like this

```
Last Changed Rev: 3303
```

I can easily compare this result with a saved value.

I want to do this for a folder containing externals. My idea was to use `svn info -R`, `grep` like above, `sort` the output and check the last line of the output. However, `svn info -R` only includes files and folders from the current repo and does not include externals! Is there any way to make it including externals? Or have I to browse the folder hierarchy myself (using a script)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out a solution. `svn status` can process externals too.

```
$ svn status -v

              7753     5689 user1        D:\checkout\file1.txt
?                                        D:\checkout\unversioned_file1.txt
?                                        D:\checkout\unversioned_file2.txt
              7753     6693 user2        D:\checkout\file2.txt
M             7753     5683 user2        D:\checkout\file3.txt
              7753     5683 user1        D:\checkout\file4.txt
```

This `awk` script can get the maximum of 3rd column which is the last change of that file.

```
{
revnum = ($1 ~ /[0-9]+/) ? $2 : $3    # $1 is number => get $2, else $3
if(revnum ~ /[0-9]+/)                 # a number? (ignore text-only lines)
  {if(revnum>max) max=revnum}         # look for maximum
}
END{print max}
```